# Flash AIR Mobile - Dirty Regions in GPU renderMode

Tags: flash, air, gpu

I just profiled my AIR Mobile application using Adobe Scout, and found something very strange and interesting:

- I had a stage with a couple of dozens DisplayObjects on it
- In a specific frame, only **one** DisplayObject actually moved one pixel to the right
- I was expecting to see a Dirty Region equivalent to the size of that DisplayObject (plus its pixel movement)
- However, I noticed that the Dirty Region was in the size of the **Entire Stage**

When running my application in renderMode=CPU (although not on mobile, but on an HTML Canvas) - the Dirty Region was indeed equivalent to the DisplayObject's size (+1 pixel)

How can we explain this?

Does GPU mode ignore Dirty Regions and just render the entire stage on every frame?

Does it make sense in any way?

Thanks in advanced

Eyal

Comment: Ever find an answer?